# React router dom Link navigate to page on the same level OR replace only the end of current URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `<Link/>` from `react-router-dom` for navigation. And I wanted to switch the page at the curent level I am at, meaning to only change the last endpoint.

I have a url structure with the following hierarchy

```
/animals/cat
/animals/dog
```

And I wanted to go to `dog` while I am in the `cat` page using `<Link/`> and vice versa.
Is there an easier way to change only the last endpoint `cat` to `dog` when using link in the page?

## What I tried

This append `/dog` at the end of whatever url I am at

```
<Link to="./dog">   //leads to the url /cat/dog  instead of /animals/dog
<Link to="dog">     //leads to the url /cat/dog  instead of /animals/dog
```

And this replace everything on the url to `/dog`

```
<Link to="/dog">    //leads to the url /dog      instead of /animals/dog
<Link to="../dog">  //leads to the url /dog      instead of /animals/dog
```

Is there an easy way to do this on the `Link` component itself instead of using hooks or some other methods?

Comment: `to="../dog"` should probably be the correct version to navigate to a "sibling" path, but it depends on where the link is being rendered and what it is relative to. It appears to be rendered at the `"/animals"` path level. Can you include a more complete code example that may explain why that doesn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese using `to="../dog"` actually clears all path and puts `/dog` like `https://localhost:300/dog`

Comment: Right, I get that, but that is the syntax used to navigate to another path on the same level, but it depends on the level the link is rendered. Like I said, it seems the link is rendered on the parent level, so `".."` will go up a level from the parent level, `"/"` in this case.

Comment: I know `..` leads to the parent, but I wanted to go to the parent's another child, ie. `animals/cats` from when clicking a link while I am on  `animals/dogs`.

Comment: Right, again, what you are wanting to do is understood, and again, it depends on *where* the link is rendered and what it can relatively link to. You've only shown the link in isolation. We need to see the whole picture, i.e. the routes and links and what/where/how they relate to one another.

Comment: I am currently in `/dogs`, and that is what is being rendered.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your question. The current page rendered with the `<Link/>` has the path `http://localhost:3000/animals/dog`. And when clicking a `<Link/>`, I wanted to go to `http://localhost:3000/animals/cat`

Comment: It depends on *where* the link is being rendered. If the link is rendered in `"/animals"` then `to="../dogs"` will navigate to `"/dogs"`, but if the link is rendered in `"/animals/cats"` then `to="../dogs"` will navigate to `"/animals/dogs"`. Is it making sense now why we need to see where the link is being rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following hook

```
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

const location = useLocation();
<Link to={useLocation().pathname + "/../dog"}/>
```

write if you have better solutions

Answer (score 0):

umm Im Not sure if you want this or something else, all you gotta do is

```
<Link to="/animals/dog"/>
```