# How to recognize when you're on that particular path using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React router to navigate to different pages in my react app. In my footer, I have a link to a /about path. When I click that link it takes me to localhost:3000/about. However, when I click it again it takes me to localhost:3000/about/about. How do I avoid this?  Below are my routes:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="privacy" element={<Privacy />} />
        <Route path="templates" element={<Templates />} />
        <Route path="template-one" element={<TemplateOne />} />
        <Route path="template-two" element={<TemplateTwo />} />
        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Footer:

```
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer className={classes.footer}>
        <div className={classes.footerLinks}>
          <h2>Company</h2>
          <Link to="about" exact>
            About
          </Link>
          <Link to="privacy" exact>
            Privacy
          </Link>
          <Link to="/">Expectations</Link>
        </div>
    </footer>
  );
};
```

Comment: Add / infront of your paths.. eg. <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />                Regarding your questions, the problem was in the Link of the footer component.. please share the code too..

Comment: @sms I added the footer component.

Comment: First do as @sms said, then inside Footer it should be `<Link to="/about" exact>` and `<Link to="/privacy" exact>`. Adds the `/` or it would take into account your current location.

Comment: Yes adding the "/" fixed it. Didn't realize you had to do this. Thanks guys. @yousoumar

Answer (score 0):

Use `/` on your link

```
<Link to="/about">About</Link>
```

And if you are on sub level, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121778/react-router-dom-link-navigate-to-page-on-the-same-level-or-replace-only-the-end) is a question that answers the problem of switching only the last path in the endpoint. As the answer shows, you can use `useLocation` hook to know about the current location you are on.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue here is that the links the footer is rendering are using ***relative*** paths instead of ***absolute*** paths.

```
<Link to="about">About</Link>
```

With `to="about"` when clicked the link will navigate relative to the current matched path to `".../about"`.

Examples:

- "/" -> "/about"
- "/about" -> "/about/about"
- "/contact" -> "/contact/about"

The difference between relative and absolute paths is simple; absolute paths start with a leading `"/"` while relative paths do not.

## Solution

Prepend a `"/"` to the links you want to use absolute paths.

```
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer className={classes.footer}>
        <div className={classes.footerLinks}>
          <h2>Company</h2>
          <Link to="/about">   // <-- absolute path
            About
          </Link>
          <Link to="/privacy"> // <-- absolute path
            Privacy
          </Link>
          <Link to="/">Expectations</Link>
        </div>
    </footer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding /asterisk  (/*) in each route path.

```html
<Route path="about/*" element={<About />} />
```